# Limit of an elliptic integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

Exercise:
$$F(y):=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}} dx$$ where $k$ is a constant in the range $0 ≤ k < 1$.Show that the limit $$L:=\lim \limits_{y \to 1^-} F(y)$$exists and that $$L<\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$$

I thought that if it is possible to show that the function is strictly increasing in the interval $(-1,1)$ and is bounded from above, then the existence of the limit can be proved according to the axiom of completeness.

Take any $x_1,x_2$ such that $-1<x_1<x_2<1$ then $$F(x_2)-F(x_1)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}} dx >0$$

But I couldn't proceed because couldn't find an upper bound for this integral.
Could anybody help me, please.

Comment: How can the dummy variable of integral appear as bounds?

Comment: k is not  variable  it is a constant

Comment: Using the substitution $x=\sin t$ you can write the integral as $F(y) =\int_0^{\arcsin y} \frac{dt} {\sqrt {1-k^2\sin^2t}}$ and this integral exists for all values of $y\in [0,1]$ so your limit $L$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $F(y)$ is increasing hence the limit (proper or improper) exists. We have $$F(y)\le {1\over \sqrt{1-k^2}}\int\limits_0^y{1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\ ={1\over \sqrt{1-k^2}}\arcsin y\le {\pi\over 2}{1\over \sqrt{1-k^2}}$$ Therefore $$L\le {\pi\over 2}{1\over \sqrt{1-k^2}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = \sin\theta$. Then, by using that  $\frac{d}{d\theta} \sin\theta = \cos\theta$,
$$ L = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} d\theta \le \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-k^2}},$$
because $\pi < 4$.